# Powershell listing size of files

Tags: powershell

I have 3600 files named PKA.dump

One of these files is not the right size. They should be above 500bytes, but one is below 500. Is there a way to check all subsubfolders and find the one file named PKA.dump that is less than 500 bytes?

Sorry I meant to add I am using powershell.

I had it working in linux, but powershell is so new to me

Comment: Does it have to be done via PowerShell? Also, which version of Windows?

Comment: Powershell or CMD with windows 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\PATH\TO\Folder\pka.dump -recurse | Where-Object{$_.Length -lt 500}
```